# Getting frequent usage day in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have table which has travel date for each user_id. I have derived a `day of week` column from date.

Table

```
+------+----------------+-----------+
| user | Date of Travel | DayofWeek |
+------+----------------+-----------+
|    1 | 2019-07-22     | Monday    |
|    1 | 2019-07-22     | Monday    |
|    1 | 2019-07-29     | Monday    |
|    1 | 2019-08-05     | Monday    |
|    1 | 2019-08-06     | Tuesday   |
|    2 | 2019-07-24     | Wednesday |
|    2 | 2019-07-24     | Wednesday |
|    2 | 2019-07-31     | Wednesday |
|    2 | 2019-08-07     | Wednesday |
|    2 | 2019-08-06     | Tuesday   |
+------+----------------+-----------+
```

For each user I want his most frequent travel day. The desired output as as below

```
+------+---------------------+
| user | Frequent_Travel_Day |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | Monday              |
|    2 | Wednesday           |
+------+---------------------+
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your database tags are inconsistent.  You should tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated, my bad

Comment: If one of these answers solve your problem. Then you should  accept it  by on clicking the check mark beside it to toggle from grayed out to fill in. @sql_learner

Comment: @Pie Both of them are helpful.

Comment: which one is easier for you @sql_learner

Comment: @Pie Marked it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In statistics, this is called the *mode*.  You can do this with window functions and aggregation:

```
select user, dayofweek
from (select user, dayofweek, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by user, dayofweek
     ) ud
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [user], DayOfWeek AS Frequent_Travel_Day
FROM tab
GROUP BY [user], DayOfWeek
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b53a3e4dbad2583c24fa13184c6f141)**

Output:

```
user    DayOfWeek
1       Monday
2       Wednesday
```